# SQL SERVER 2014 SUM Function doesn't return correct value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a data as below, when I total Wage_Value it should give me 0 value

[image]

However SQL SERVER `SUM` function doesn't return correct value (see result below).

The data type of `Wage_Value` is **decimal(18,2)**.

```
select [Employee Code], Wage_Type, sum(Wage_Value) 'Total_Wage_Value'
from [SSO_PAYROLL_20151231]
where [Employee Code] = '3870299'
group by [Employee Code], Wage_Type
```

[image]

Comment: Select ... cast(sum(Wage_Value) as decimal(18,2)) ... and you will see the zero you want to see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe you.  I think the type of `Wage_Value` is a floating point number, not a decimal.  SQL Server is quite explicit about the output type of a `sum()`.  For a decimal input, the output is decimal.  See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx).

Also, because the values are sometimes output with one decimal place and sometimes with 2 ("852.9" and "-317.07"), I think the representation is a floating point number.

This is easy enough to check.  Do an explicit conversion:

```
select [Employee Code], Wage_Type,
       sum(cast(Wage_Value as decimal(18, 2)) as Total_Wage_Value
from [SSO_PAYROLL_20151231]
where [Employee Code] = '3870299'
group by [Employee Code], Wage_Type
```

Comment: I confirmed the data type is decimal(18,2).

Comment: After cast function. I managed to get corrected value. Just wonder why need to do cast function.

Comment: Tip: You can display the data type of a column or expression: `select SQL_Variant_Property( Wage_Value, 'BaseType' )`. [`SQL_Variant_Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx) can also return precision, scale, ... .